# Does $a_n = (2+\sqrt{3})^n$ diverge or converge? If it converges, find the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I recently had this question on an exam and this was my approach to solving:

Let $b_n = 2^n$, $c_n = n$. By the Archimedean Order Property of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists an n* $\in \mathbb{Z^+}$ such that n* > n, thus $C_n$ is unbounded and therefore diverges to $+\infty$. Since $b_n \ge c_n$, for $n \ge 1$, then by the Comparison Theorem, $b_n$ also diverges to $+\infty$. And since $a_n > b_n$ for $n \ge 1$, $a_n$ also diverges to $+\infty$.

I got almost no points on this answer, and I'm not sure what is wrong with my proof.

Comment: You might have proved that $(2+\sqrt{3})^n>2^n$ by taking roots and $2^n>n$ by induction. Those parts are missing. But, this is not a bad solution. Your teacher is harsh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show that $b_n\geq c_n$ and $a_n\geq b_n$ I know it sounds obvious to you but you need to prove that for your instructor.